# Нестандартная форма контейнера (html-кросс)

Tags: svg, canvas, html5, кроссбраузерность

День добрый!

При всей своей первоначальной бредовости, вопрос оказался очень забавным:

Есть народ, который привык рисовать дизайны в стиле Flash на весь экран, ну и радостно их на нем воплощать. На аргументацию, что на куче новых девайсов этот сайт просто не откроется, да и СЕО страдает - не "ведется")

Предмет дискуссии, возможна ли верстка аляповатого дизайна, с множеством элементов нестандартной формы (кружечки, многоугольнички) и примитивной анимацией на чистом html+css+js с сохранением однотипности отображения в браузерах (iOS, android, old-IE).

Извращались ли вы таким образом и как?

Спасибо!

Comment: > Предмет дискуссии

> Извращались ли вы таким образом и как?

что-то очень похоже на опрос, а не вопрос :)

Comment: Да вполне реализуемо, все эти кружочки, анимация, музыка. Просто чуть сложнее.

Comment: 2IVsevolod. Ну в общем - наверно даже да)

То, что нужно я сделал еще в день вопроса, бит-прозрачные PNG+jQuery... Вышло чуть тяжеловато, но зато работает на IE6, 2ом айфоне и дроиде... Заказчик забрызгал радастю и щастем все стены, гад))

Но как-кто делал - все равно интересно.